# rendering query x times instead of required once because instance... help?

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to return a custom query, which renders each row once, however sometimes the table it queries is the same... For example. My output code currently is this...

```
//Query one returns each instance of an object. There are two of the first, one of the second.
13775
13775
66777

//Query two returns each bit of information against the first object. 
// As you can see its loading the first too twice because of the query above being the same...
SID=13775 TOKEN=b8r5x6w53d6cahw
SID=13775 TOKEN=p5ugbeg68b4qixy

SID=13775 TOKEN=b8r5x6w53d6cahw
SID=13775 TOKEN=p5ugbeg68b4qixy

SID=66777 TOKEN=4c85zznh955gjsc
```

My code is as follows for the above display...

//Query table where firstname, lastname and email all match

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM lime_all_tokens WHERE fname='".$fname."' AND lname ='".$lname."'";

//execute query
$result = mysql_query($query) or die ("Error in query: $query. ".mysql_error());

$sid = array();

// see if any rows were returned
if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    // yes
    // print them one after another
    $i = 0;
    while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
        //Shows the SID's
        echo $row[5]."<br />";

        //Add into the DB in order...
        $sid[] = $row[5];   
        $i++;     
    }       
}

// free result set memory
mysql_free_result($result);

for ($j = 0; $j < $i; $j++) {
    $querytokens = "SELECT * FROM lime_tokens_".$sid[$j]." WHERE firstname='".$fname."' AND lastname ='".$lname."'";

    echo $tokens[$j]."<br />";

    //execute query
    $resulttokens = mysql_query($querytokens) or die ("Error in query: $querytokens. ".mysql_error());

    // see if any rows were returned

    //print_r(mysql_fetch_row($resulttokens));

    while($rowtokens = mysql_fetch_row($resulttokens)) {        
        //Display our token
        echo "SID=".$sid[$j]." TOKEN=".$rowtokens[5]."<br />";
        $displayonce = false;
    }       

}


echo "<br /><br /><h2>There are a total of ".$i." calls availible!</h2>";

// free result set memory
mysql_free_result($resulttokens);

// close connection
mysql_close($connection);
```

How can i get it to return the data properly? i.e

```
13775
13775
66777

SID=13775 TOKEN=b8r5x6w53d6cahw

SID=13775 TOKEN=p5ugbeg68b4qixy

SID=66777 TOKEN=4c85zznh955gjsc
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMHO you could change first query to:

```
SELECT DISTINCT id 
FROM lime_all_tokens 
WHERE fname='".$fname."' AND lname ='".$lname."'"
```

Comment: Could you please explain the benifits of this?

Comment: @Graeme: Maybe if you understand what it does, helps to see if it's a benefit for you? See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html for the docs.

Comment: Ive had a quick look, however, I do not want to ommit data, i want to include it... So it looks at a different "row" so to speak each time it goes through the 2nd query in the for statement...

Comment: @Graeme: in your first query you get duplicated IDs, so when you use second query (querying tables which name is composed with those IDs) you get duplicate rows. So the only solution is getting not duplicated IDs with your first query using my example. You cannot use JOINS because you're composing tables names with a query, so that's not a way. If you don't want to omit records with first query, you could use that, than use my query whose results are to be used with the third

Comment: Ive actually solved this... by created an array and populating it with the unique tokens as its goes along, then in the while loop it checks to see if the token is present in that array and skips if it is...

Comment: @Graeme: let me tell you that your solution (even if it's correct and was one that I had in my mind) is heavier and harder to maintain than doing another query like mine!!